# SQL Server 2008 SSMS connection and http connection string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, database-connection

I have a SQL Server 2008 on a server which goes out on the internet through a domain name               **computer.example.com**, I want to develop a .net app on my PC and to connect to that database through SSMS - to create tables and so on...
And I still want a connection string which can be accessed from anywhere - I'm thinking at a http url or something like that - which will be consumed by the app.

What do I must to configure on the server so that I can connect via SSMS to the database (from my PC) and how do I get a connection string to that database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Sql Server Configuration Manager` for this work. when you run this application, expand the `SQL Server Network Configuration`, after that you can see Protocols for sql server 2008. by click on it you can enable or disable TCP/IP.

your connection string can be like this :

```
connectionString="Database=DBName;Server = Server IP;Integrated Security=false;user id=sa; password=Pass;
```